# Reference table data through CSS?

Tags: html, css, reference

Hi Stack overflow community, I had the following HTML code

```
<td data-th="Select" aria-label="Select " tabindex="0" role="checkbox"></td>
```

I was wondering is there any possible way to reference this through CSS? If so how?

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly but maybe you are looking for a selector for this node? Check for [Attribute Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) something like this `td[tabindex="0"]`

Comment: @Baro how would I reference this via CSS to display none?

Comment: also @Baro tab index is used elsewhere

Comment: i want to reference <td data-th="Select"> and display none through css

Comment: I wrote you the logic and I gave you a link to understand how it works, then you should adapt it to your needs. However the important thing is that the reference is unique, if `data-th` is your unique attribute then `td[data-th="Select"]`

Comment: @Baro would I reference this throguh CSS and display it as none?

Comment: Paulie_D wrote you the complete answer with the example.

Comment: @Baro this is brilliant wow so cool, what about this one if I want to get rid of the word "Title", here is my HTML <td data-type="System.String" 
data-attribute="title" tabindex="0" data-th="Title">
</td>

Comment: Mate you have all examples and links for understand the logic. `[Attribute=Value]` really simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data attribute is unique you could target that:

```css
td[data-th="Select"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Nothing</td>
    <td data-th="Select" aria-label="Select " tabindex="0" role="checkbox">Hidden</td>
    <td>Here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) matches elements based on the presence or value of a given attribute. So, you can use the selector `[attr=value]` to match an element with an attribute `attr` whose value is `value`. In your case, the selector `[data-th="Select"]` will work:

```css
td[data-th="Select"] {
    display: none;
}

.table td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Some data</td>
    <td data-th="Select" aria-label="Select " tabindex="0" role="checkbox">Data to hide</td>
    <td>Other data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you please share an example of how [attr=value] can be used?

Comment: I've added an example code snippet. I didn't see the need to do that since @Paulie_D's answer provides a good example.

Comment: how would I do [attr=value]?